# Make an SKSpriteNode fall without collisions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, gravity, skspritenode

Is there a way to get make an SKSpriteNode fall as if under the affect of gravity, without interacting with any objects it collides with on its way down (e.g. passing right through them)? Making the object's SKPhysicsBody dynamic and setting its 'affectedByGravity' property to true causes the falling object to bump into things.

Comment: Set the physics body's `collisionBitMask` to 0

Comment: It worked! Thank you!